# No audio in Ep. 455 and discrepancy in episode numbers

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, podcast

[Today's episode](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/06/21/an-engineers-field-guide-to-great-technical-writing-ep-455/) "An Engineer’s Field Guide to Great Technical Writing (Ep. 455)" doesn't have audio (this seems fixed now). Error message is:

> 404
>
> Audio Not Found

[image: first screenshot of podcast]

The episode numbers in the title (**ep. 455**) and inside the player (**ep. 466**) also seem to be different:

[image: second screenshot of player]

Comment: What player? I [downloaded](https://chrt.fm/track/G8F1AF/cdn.simplecast.com/audio/6fa1d34c-502b-4abf-bd82-483804006e0b/episodes/d7cf9e89-ab85-43d4-8c1b-abb4567526cc/audio/28b03da8-4931-4203-aeeb-8f8cfb43261b/default_tc.mp3?aid=rss_feed&feed=XA_851k3) the MP3 file for the episode ***more than 8 hours ago*** through [the RSS feed](https://feeds.simplecast.com/XA_851k3) and it was fine. ([Thunderbird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Thunderbird) as the RSS reader (sort of a hidden feature).)

Comment: I would guess [SoundCloud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SoundCloud) (I [block JavaScript by default](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoScript)).

Comment: I figured out why the podcast numbers don't match. They're fine up till episode #256. But there are other podcasts in the middle which do not continue the number in the title of the blog post, but do so in the title of the *player*. See [page 19](https://stackoverflow.blog/podcast/page/19/).

Comment: **Everyone, stop closing questions as can't be reproduced just because it was fixed!!!!!!!** For heaven's sake, of course it can't be reproduced anymore, it was, well, FIXED.

Comment: @Luuklag well that's a mess currently as one bug turned out to be not really a bug, as the answer explains. Since this marked completed, the part about episode numbers mismatch should, ideally, be moved to a new question and the relevant part from the answer posted as answer there. But frankly that's just not worth the hassle. All in all, this does not  "justify" closing with wrong reason to begin with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The audio issue in the podcast player [has been fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/379704/no-audio-in-ep-455-and-discrepancy-in-episode-numbers/379706#comment1266867_379704):

[image]

---

Regarding the mismatch in the episode numbers, at some point(s), there were other podcasts (different from the usual stream of podcasts) which did not include the episode number in the title of their respective blog posts, but they still counted as episodes.

For example, there is no discrepancy in the numbers from [Podcast episode 220](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/24/podcast-episode-220-remote-work-lets-encrypt-bug/) to [Podcast #256](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/07/28/podcast-256-gpt-3-anxiety-job-interview/), but there are two blog posts after it (*[Podcast – 25 Years of Java: the past to the present](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/07/29/podcast-sponsored-25-years-of-java-oracle/)* and *[Java at 25: Features that made an impact and a look to the future](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/07/30/java-at-25-features-that-made-an-impact-and-a-look-to-the-future/)*), whose titles did *not* include the numbers **257** and **258** (as they were different from the usual stream of podcasts<sup>1</sup>), but the podcast players *did* include these numbers (as they still counted as episodes). So the count for the *usual* stream of podcasts continued from where it had last stopped (i.e., 256), and therefore, [Podcast #257](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/08/04/podcast-257-a-few-of-our-favorite-haxx/) has **259** in the header of the player.

[image]

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> There's a note in the [first blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/07/29/podcast-sponsored-25-years-of-java-oracle/) that reads: *This week we have two extra podcast episodes for you, sponsored by Oracle, which is celebrating 25 years since the creation of the Java programming language. This is part one. You can find part two [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/07/30/java-at-25-features-that-made-an-impact-and-a-look-to-the-future/?_ga=2.167123646.1656447535.1648210232-1516763786.1633275047).*</sup>